# How can public access to WordPress query (e.g. author=) URLs be redirected?

Tags: redirect, author

I maintain a WordPress site (I'm a programmer but don't have much WordPress experience), and we've noticed that Google is ending up with high-ranked links to "pages" on the WordPress site that we don't really want to be available, such as:

> sitename.net/?author=2

which lists a dump of all pages written by author number 2, which were supposed to only be viewed in a certain way where they're organized and presented as intended. Is there a way to disable this feature, and/or redirect links to such things to the main site or some other relevant URL?

Comment: A quick search on this site [for 'redirect_author_pages'](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=redirect+author+pages) can help, one answer that may be able to help you out or point you in the right direction is http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-to-hide-redirect-the-author-page

Comment: The key points being to hook into the `template_redirect` hook so that you can safely redirect to another page, and within that hook you can check if the current page is an author page by calling `is_author`

Comment: I see how to write the condition code for a filter function as in the second link. But I don't know where to add such code, or how to get it to run at the right time. I searched up wpa_parse_query in a few places on my site, but it's in dense machine-generated scripts as far as I've seen so far. My site is based on the twenty-twelve template. Any pointers to how to correctly insert such a condition for page requests?

Comment: Add the filter function code into the `functions.php` file in your twenty-twelve theme directory

Answer (score 0):

Based on @czerspalace 's tips, I seem to have created a working filter for this.

I added the following function to the functions.php file in my twenty-twelve theme directory:

```
function redirect_author_query_to_home( $query ){
    if( is_author() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'redirect_author_query_to_home' );
```

Comment: Any specific reason you used `parse_query` instead of `template_redirect`?

Comment: I based it on the accepted answer to the question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95920/how-do-i-remove-unwanted-pages-like-archive-search-etc/98741#98741 . I don't know what the difference is between the two, even after reading both https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect .